# Spring Batch does not commit when using Repository.save() statements

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-data-jpa

Good day,

I am trying to re-use my repositories written as part of a core module in a batch module in a multi-module maven Spring Boot project. No matter what I do, the Repository.save() methods do not commit the changes to the database.

At the moment tried using a Tasklet that call a Service component that performs the Repository operations. Even though I mark that Repository or Service as requiring a transaction, the inserts/updates are not committed to the database.

Is there a way to overcome this or must I re-configure the database connection and re-write the JPA entities in the batch module?

Kind regards,
Mark P Ashworth

Comment: have you tried using `Repository.saveAndFlush(..)`

Comment: post your code . Use Flush after save

Comment: repository or service should not be annotated with transaction directive because transaction lifecycle is directly managed by SB

Comment: Never use the same transaction manager that is being used by spring batch if you are trying to commit the changes that is not the part of spring batch .

Comment: Please post your code for the advise on fix or analysis